# Имеет ли значение, в каком порядке посылаются HTTP заголовки?

Tags: http

Могу ли я изменять порядок следования таких заголовков, как Host и Content-Length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разницы нет. Но есть рекомендации в части размещения групп заголовков, об этом так же [написано в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_HTTP).

> Все заголовки разделяются на четыре
> основных группы:
>
> - **General Headers** (рус. Основные    заголовки) — должны включаться в 
>   любое сообщение клиента и сервера.
> - **Request Headers** (рус. Заголовки    запроса) — используются только в 
>   запросах клиента.
> - **Response Headers** (рус. Заголовки    ответа) — только для ответов от 
>   сервера.
> - **Entity Headers** (рус. Заголовки    сущности) — сопровождают каждую 
>   сущность сообщения (может относиться
>   как к клиенту, так и к серверу).
>
> Именно в таком порядке рекомендуется
> посылать заголовки получателю
> (программно это не имеет значения,
> однако даёт удобство при отладке).